# Make new feature using 2 tables

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

```
table1 <- data.frame(user_id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 product_id = c(14, 24, 38, 40, 66, 2, 19, 30, 71, 98, 7, 16),
                 first_order = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3),
                 last_order = c(4, 7, 5, 8, 8, 3, 4, 7, 5, 9, 4, 5))
table2 <- data.frame(user_id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 order_number=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 days_cumsum = c(0, 7, 15, 26, 34, 43, 53, 59, 66, 74, 82, 91, 5, 11, 17, 24, 29, 35))
```

***I want to add new feature to table1 using table2.***
**New feature is order interval of each product by each user.**

For example, let's see the table1. First row has (user_id==1), (product_id==14), (first order==1) and (last order ==4). It means product 14 was ordered at order 1, 2, 3, 4. And we can find this order number in table 2. 
New feature is about order interval between first order and last order. We can derive it in table 2, using "days_cumsum" which is cumulative sum of days after prior order. First row's new feature value is 26(=26-0).

I think it may be done with join, but ***I can't use join*** because each table is very big actually.

So I'm using this function below with for loop :

```
f <- function(i){
  a <- table2 %>% 
    filter(user_id==table1[i, 1]) %>% 
    filter(order_number==table1[i, 3] | order_number==table1[i, 4])

  ifelse(nrow(a)==2, a[2, 3] - a[1, 3], 999999) # first_order==last_order
}
```

It calculates each new feature value row by row, but it is very slow and needs many calculation. I often encounter this problem(make new feature using two tables), but every time I have difficulties.

Is there better code? I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: What is the expected output for given example ?

Comment: sorry, have an error in the code. i'll edit

Comment: @RonakShah error corrected. you can use edited table2.
Use function in the code, you can get the new feature value.
Expected output : each new feature value added in table1[5]

Comment: See if this works for your dataset : `table1$new_feature <- apply(table1, 1, function(x) sum(table2$days_cumsum[x[["user_id"]] == table2$user_id &
    table2$order_number >= x[["first_order"]] & table2$order_number < x[["last_order"]]]))`. I am using `apply` here so don't think it helps in efficiency.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you but it is different from expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share the runtime/computation time comparisons for `join` and the version using your loop?

Below is a solution using joins.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- as.data.frame(table1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(table2)


df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("user_id"="user_id", "first_order" = "order_number")) %>%
  rename(dayMin = days_cumsum) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("user_id"="user_id", "last_order" = "order_number")) %>%
  rename(dayMax = days_cumsum) %>%
  mutate(newVar = dayMax-dayMin) %>%
  select(user_id, product_id, first_order, last_order, newVar)
```

which gives:

```
   user_id product_id first_order last_order newVar
     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1         14           1          4     26
 2       1         24           2          7     46
 3       1         38           1          5     34
 4       1         40           4          8     33
 5       1         66           5          8     25
 6       1          2           3          3      0
 7       1         19           2          4     19
 8       1         30           4          7     27
 9       1         71           2          5     27
10       1         98           4          9     40
11       2          7           2          4     13
12       2         16           3          5     12
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm running my code now on aws instance. I'll test it and let you know when the task is over.

Comment: My aws instance is still working. So I measure performance with sample data above. Your code is great! I used microbenchmark to measure. Your code gets 6.59 while my function gets 50.42.
I really appreciate it. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help. In case the second dataframe df2 has too many columns, you can plug `select` statements after each `left_join` to get rid of unwanted columns. :)

Comment: Wow!  I expected this task takes over 30 hours using my function.  And I've just applied your code to my actual data. Your code takes only 9 seconds! omg!

Comment: I think the reason of the difference is data size. Actually, df1 has 13307953 rows and df2 has 3214874 rows. 
Thanks to you I realized the efficiency of the code. I really appreaciate it again!

Comment: that's awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

For comparaison, some solutions using `data.table`.

```r
table1 <- data.frame(user_id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                     product_id = c(14, 24, 38, 40, 66, 2, 19, 30, 71, 98, 7, 16),
                     first_order = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3),
                     last_order = c(4, 7, 5, 8, 8, 3, 4, 7, 5, 9, 4, 5))
table2 <- data.frame(user_id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                     order_number=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                     days_cumsum = c(0, 7, 15, 26, 34, 43, 53, 59, 66, 74, 82, 91, 5, 11, 17, 24, 29, 35))

library(data.table)

setDT(table1)
setDT(table2)

table1
#>     user_id product_id first_order last_order
#>  1:       1         14           1          4
#>  2:       1         24           2          7
#>  3:       1         38           1          5
#>  4:       1         40           4          8
#>  5:       1         66           5          8
#>  6:       1          2           3          3
#>  7:       1         19           2          4
#>  8:       1         30           4          7
#>  9:       1         71           2          5
#> 10:       1         98           4          9
#> 11:       2          7           2          4
#> 12:       2         16           3          5
table2
#>     user_id order_number days_cumsum
#>  1:       1            1           0
#>  2:       1            2           7
#>  3:       1            3          15
#>  4:       1            4          26
#>  5:       1            5          34
#>  6:       1            6          43
#>  7:       1            7          53
#>  8:       1            8          59
#>  9:       1            9          66
#> 10:       1           10          74
#> 11:       1           11          82
#> 12:       1           12          91
#> 13:       2            1           5
#> 14:       2            2          11
#> 15:       2            3          17
#> 16:       2            4          24
#> 17:       2            5          29
#> 18:       2            6          35

DayMin <- table1[table2, on = .(user_id, first_order = order_number), nomatch = 0]
setnames(DayMin, "days_cumsum", "dayMin")
DayMax <- table1[table2, on = .(user_id, last_order = order_number), nomatch = 0]
setnames(DayMax, "days_cumsum", "dayMax")
res <- DayMin[DayMax, on = .(user_id, product_id, first_order, last_order)]
# calculate diff and delete column
res[, c("diff", "dayMax", "dayMin") := list(dayMax - dayMin, NULL, NULL)]
res[]
#>     user_id product_id first_order last_order diff
#>  1:       1          2           3          3    0
#>  2:       1         14           1          4   26
#>  3:       1         19           2          4   19
#>  4:       1         38           1          5   34
#>  5:       1         71           2          5   27
#>  6:       1         24           2          7   46
#>  7:       1         30           4          7   27
#>  8:       1         40           4          8   33
#>  9:       1         66           5          8   25
#> 10:       1         98           4          9   40
#> 11:       2          7           2          4   13
#> 12:       2         16           3          5   12
```

"piped-like" version without renaming

```r
table1[table2, on = .(user_id, first_order = order_number), nomatch = 0][
    table2, on = .(user_id , last_order = order_number), nomatch = 0][
      , `:=`(
        diff = i.days_cumsum - days_cumsum, 
        days_cumsum = NULL, 
        i.days_cumsum = NULL
      )][]
#>     user_id product_id first_order last_order diff
#>  1:       1          2           3          3    0
#>  2:       1         14           1          4   26
#>  3:       1         19           2          4   19
#>  4:       1         38           1          5   34
#>  5:       1         71           2          5   27
#>  6:       1         24           2          7   46
#>  7:       1         30           4          7   27
#>  8:       1         40           4          8   33
#>  9:       1         66           5          8   25
#> 10:       1         98           4          9   40
#> 11:       2          7           2          4   13
#> 12:       2         16           3          5   12
```

using reshaping for one merge only

```r
tab <- melt(table1, id = 1:2, value.name = "order_number")[table2, on = .(user_id, order_number), nomatch = 0]
res <- dcast(tab, user_id + product_id ~ variable, value.var = c("order_number", "days_cumsum"), sep = "#")
setnames(res, c("user_id", "product_id", "first_order", "last_order", "dayMin", "dayMax"))
res[, c("diff", "dayMax", "dayMin") := list(dayMax - dayMin, NULL, NULL)]
res
#>     user_id product_id first_order last_order diff
#>  1:       1          2           3          3    0
#>  2:       1         14           1          4   26
#>  3:       1         19           2          4   19
#>  4:       1         24           2          7   46
#>  5:       1         30           4          7   27
#>  6:       1         38           1          5   34
#>  7:       1         40           4          8   33
#>  8:       1         66           5          8   25
#>  9:       1         71           2          5   27
#> 10:       1         98           4          9   40
#> 11:       2          7           2          4   13
#> 12:       2         16           3          5   12
```

Comment: I know only a basics of data.table. I should study more with your codes. Thanks!