# Can I quit a tab running rstudio server in aws?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio, rstudio-server

I opened a EC2 using Louis Aslett's R Studio server AMI.
I have a R script to takes a long time to perform the task.
How can I maintain the task running without rstudio tab opened in chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I host an instance of rstudio-server and mostly use it remotely via chrome on my laptop, and closing the browser tab does not affect the server computation. Often running scripts overnight.

The browser just provides a front-end interface, and as long as you're not killing the AWS session, it should be fine to close the tab.

Comment: Thank you! If i don't push "quit the current R session" button on the right top side on the rstudio screen, all the environment and history are remained?

Comment: Exactly. Also, in case you want to save the environment variables, you can always put them in a [file](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/workspace.html) . p.s. make sure you're not calling `q()` anywhere within your script.

Comment: Could you help me for my other question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558169/make-new-feature-using-2-tables